# How do I center align my links on the 100% width navigation bars?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, center

I would like to know how to center align all of the links on my two navigation bars. ( one at the top and one at the bottom ). I've tried the text-align code and it didn't work for some reason. Please can you help me solve this problem.

For some reason I can't post the code sample so please visit this link to view the source code: http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/mxjgtv/Index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple working example below:

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="Videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="Results.html">RESULTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="Tumblr.html">TUMBLR</a></li>
</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Other points:

- Don't wrap your elements in the  tag. The  tag is deprecated: https://caniuse.com/#search=center
- Start learning flexbox to build up your layout: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- Use a  tag instead of a  tag to wrap your navigation, to help search engines crawl your website properly by adding semantics: http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Comment: Thank you this works. However the links are all too close to the top of the navbar border.

Comment: I only tried to solve your main issue which is to align the content in the center. To adjust the alignment use padding / line-height on the <a> children elements of the <nav> parent element.

Answer (score 0):

For the first navigation bar remove the `float` property and add `text-align:center`

```
.navbar a {
   text-align: center;  //<---------------add this 
    display: inline;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For the second navigation at the bottom add just add the `text-align` property

```
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px;text-align: center;">
  <a href="http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/">HG CARPENTRY</a>
  <a href="Allrightsreserved.html">ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</a>
  <a href="PrivacyPolicy.Terms.html">TERMS & CONDITIONS</a>
  <a href="PrivacyPolicy.html">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
   </div>
```